# Should the first letter of a thought be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, thought

Should the first letter of a thought be capitalized?

Like for example in this sentence:

> Birds were chirping cheerful little song but I don’t hear them all I can hear is my thoughts *where am I don’t remember going his way* and my heart beat ‘bumbum’ ‘bumbum’.

Should the W in *where* be capitalized?

Comment: It depends on how you punctuate it. Right now you have nearly zero punctuation.

Comment: This isn't a standard way to represent thoughts (in English you'd normally use quotation marks, no different to speech). Did you copy it from somewhere or did you invent it yourself?

Comment: No I found that this is the normal way I have read books where they put thoughts like that and my ELA teacher in high school taught me to do it that way also if you look it up this is the normal way to do it. Sorry if this comes off as me being rude I am not trying to be rude.

Comment: That text is not susceptible to normal rules. It looks like a stream-of-consciousness.

How else could 'Birds were chirping cheerful little song but I don’t hear them all I can hear is my thoughts where am I don’t remember going his way and my heart beat ‘bumbum’ ‘bumbum’' be acceptable?

In proper English, the first letter of a thought should be capitalized like all other speech, just as every change of speaker needs a new paragraph.

In proper English that would mean 'Where am I…' needed both a capital and a new paragraph' but again, the passage is very clearly not proper English.

Comment: It doesn't come across as rude. It does come across as both you and your teacher being deeply confused.

In an effort to clear that up, can you say what you mean by 'if you look it up this is the normal way…'?

What, exactly, did you look up, through which search engine or dictionary?